# Java Convert String to byte[]

Tags: java, android, json

I wonder how you should do if you are going to convert an String that contains an array of bytes, actually bytes from an image into an byte array.

I guess this is a pretty common issue so i guess someone could give any suggestions.

If it is better to convert an JSONArray into an byte array i would like to know why.

Comment: Yes, it's a "pretty common issue", so, try searching for it... (-1) (Also, a String that "contains an array of bytes" already is starting to sound off...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wonder how you should do if you are going to convert an String that contains an array of bytes, actually bytes from an image into an byte array.

It depends on how you've constructed the string in the first place. If something somewhere has used

```
new String(imageData)
```

then you've already lost information, potentially. Image data *isn't* text.

To propagate opaque binary data in text, you *should* use base64 (or potentially hex). Android already has a [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class that makes this easy:

```
String text = Base64.encodeToString(originalBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

...

byte[] roundTrip = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

EDIT: If you can't use that class, [this public domain base64 encoder](http://iharder.net/base64) should work fine.

Comment: Hi Mr Jon Skeet But Base64 class comes with  api level above 7. Can you suggest any other (feasible) way  such that i can use that method in lower versions also

Answer (score 0):

Byte[] to String

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
Your_Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
String bytetostring = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
return bytetostring ;
```

String to Byte[]

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode("Your string", Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
```